# OpenCV Android UnsatisfiedLinkError while finding the Moments of Contour

Tags: android

My app installs correctly but crashes while finding the Moments of Contour. Here is the error:

> No implementation found for double[] org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.moments_1(long) (tried Java_org_opencv_imgproc_Imgproc_moments_11 and Java_org_opencv_imgproc_Imgproc_moments_11__J)